# Как передать параметр в url по клику?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Ребята, помогите плиз. Мне нужно передавать параметры в url по клику на каждую ссылку. Передать получилось, а вот заменить параметр по клику на другую ссылку, без перезагрузки страницы, не пойму как реализовать. Сейчас вообще кажется, что не тем путем пошел. Не судите строго ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var accordionTitle = $('.catalog__accordion-title');
    var accordionSubTitle = $('.catalog__accordion-item');

    accordionTitle.click(function () {

        $(".catalog__accordion .catalog__accordion-title").removeClass("active");
        $(".catalog__accordion .catalog__accordion-open").removeClass("show");

        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).next().addClass('show');//добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)

    });

    accordionSubTitle.click(function () {

        $(".catalog__accordion .catalog__accordion-item").removeClass("active");

        $(this).addClass('active');

        var $title = '#ct=' + $(this).parent().prev().data('title');

        var $subTitle = '&sub_ct=' + $(this).data('sub-title');
        var linkCollectionItemPage = $title + $subTitle;

        window.location.href += linkCollectionItemPage;
        
    });
});
```

```css
.catalog__accordion-open {
  display:none;
}
.catalog__accordion-open.show{
  display:block;
}
.catalog__accordion-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.catalog__accordion-title{
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catalog__accordion">
              <div class="catalog__accordion-head">
                <h3>Наша Продукция</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="catalog__accordion-content">
                <a class="catalog__accordion-title" href="javascript:void(0);" data-title="1">Комплексные трансформаторные подстанции</a>
                <div class="catalog__accordion-open">
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0);" data-sub-title="1">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0);" data-sub-title="2">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0);" data-sub-title="3">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0);" data-sub-title="4">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                </div>
                <a class="catalog__accordion-title" href="javascript:void(0);" data-title="2">Комплексные трансформаторные подстанции</a>
                <div class="catalog__accordion-open">
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="1">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="2">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="3">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="4">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                </div>
                <a class="catalog__accordion-title" href="javascript:void(0);" data-title="3">Комплексные трансформаторные подстанции</a>
                <div class="catalog__accordion-open">
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="1">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="2">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="3">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="4">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                </div>
                <a class="catalog__accordion-title" href="javascript:void(0);" data-title="4">Комплексные трансформаторные подстанции</a>
                <div class="catalog__accordion-open">
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="1">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="2">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="3">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="4">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                </div>
                <a class="catalog__accordion-title" href="javascript:void(0);" data-title="5">Комплексные трансформаторные подстанции</a>
                <div class="catalog__accordion-open">
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="1">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="2">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="3">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  <a class="catalog__accordion-item" href="javascript:void(0)" data-sub-title="4">Комплектные транчформаторные подстанции тупикового типа мачтовые КТПм (LE-ТПМ)</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Когда вы меняете href напрямую через window.location.href будет  происходить переход. Для того, чтобы работало, как Вы хотите, следует смотреть в направлении [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) (а конкретнее, pushState или replaceState) или подменять hash

Comment: Спасибо! pushState хорошая штука

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется вам нужно убрать `+` из это строчки:

```
window.location.href += linkCollectionItemPage;
```

Comment: Зачем его убирать, если я добавляю к url параметры из data-attr ? Посмотрите внимательнее